# Best way to modify select case in inherited class

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I am parsing an array of values with two properties (`Key` and `Value`).

Based on the keyword `Key` certain functions are called which test the `Value`.

The trouble is, I am tasked with modifying the keywords for some projects for a new project. They share like 90% of the keywords but some are unique to each project and some others are common but other functions need to be called.

At the moment the code looks like:

```
Public Structure Options
    Public Property Key
    Public Property Value
End Structure

Public Sub CheckPresentation(OptionsList as List(of Options))
    for each Elem in Optionslist
        select case elem.key
            case 1
                if elem.Value<>"bla" then
                    logger.info("bla")
                end if
            case 2
                 ...
            case 99
                 ...
       end select
    next
End Sub
```

I first wanted to simply build a new class and inherit the old class. But since all of the logic is in the select cases, that would require complete rebuilding with huge code overlap. Does anybody have an idea how to build this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a method for each of your keywords.

e.g. for your `case 1`, create the following method:

```
Sub LogIfNotBla(elem As Options)
    If elem.Value<>"bla" Then
        logger.info("bla")
    End If
End Sub
```

Do this for every keyword.

Then, create a mapping which maps each keyword to its handler using a dictionary:

```
Dim handler = new Dictionary(Of Int32, Action(Of Options)) From 
{ 
    {1,  AddressOf LogIfNotBla},
    {2,  AddressOf Foo},
    {99, AddressOf FooBar}
}
```

and instead of your gigantic `Select Case`, simply use a lookup to call the right method:

```
Public Sub CheckPresentation(OptionsList as List(of Options))
    For Each elem in Optionslist
        handler(Elem.Key)(elem)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Now you can alter the behaviour in two ways:

**Overriding**:

Mark the methods `overridable` and overwrite them in a subclass:

```
Overrides Sub LogIfNotBla(elem As Options)
    If elem.Value<>"bla" And SomeThingElse Then
        SomeOtherLogger.info("bla")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Reconfiguration**

Alter the `handler` dictionary to call other methods on specific keywords:

```
handler(1) = AddressOf AnotherMethodInsteadOfLogIfNotBla
```

Comment: Thanks that looks very promising!
I will try it and If it works as desired accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always call the base class' method for default behavior.  For instance, lets say you only want to override the behavior for keys 1, 4, and 72, you could do this in your derived class:

```
Public Overrides Sub CheckPresentation(OptionsList as List(of Options))
    For Each Elem In Optionslist
        Select Case elem.key
            Case 1
                ...
            Case 4
                ...
            Case 72
                ...
            Case Else
                MyBase.CheckPresentation(OptionsList)
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx, that would work, too - but is difficult for cases where the code inside the case has to be modified. 
I think the Solution from Mr. Steak works better here, so I will go withhis solution. Sorry guys ;)